# React JS - Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, callback, onclick, dom-events

I'm struggling to understand why my onClick function is returning me an error? The functionality is working as expected but throws the following console error:

> Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

```
{Object.keys(classGroups).map((key, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <span onClick={selectClassGroup(serving_point_id, key)}
                              className="block p-10 px-14 bg-theme-orange rounded text-white text-3xl text-center font-wicked">
                            {classGroups[key]}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                )})
            }
```

Here is my callback funtion:

```
const selectClassGroup = useCallback(
    (appId, key) => () => {
        window.location.replace('/#/serving-point/' + appId + '/' + key);
    },
    [],
)
```

What I am doing wrong for the error to appear?

Answer (score 4):

### Problem

This is a normal function call , which calls the method as soon the rendering of the component happens.

```
 <span onClick={selectClassGroup(serving_point_id, key)}
```

### Solution

use the arrow function to trigger the function **only** when onClick handler of the button is triggered.

```
 <span onClick={()=>selectClassGroup(serving_point_id, key)}
```

`()=>{}` is important to tell your onClick event that it is a function.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above but it stops my click event from firing when I click the span tag.

Comment: @heady12 I understand that you use useCallback for performance reasons, but what is the purpose of the second arrow function? 

 `useCallback((appId, key) => () => { ... }`

Comment: I think you need to update your callbackFn `useCallback((appId, key) => {return window.location.replace('/#/serving-point/' + appId + '/' + key);}`

Comment: I copied from tutorial about useCallBack, still trying to learn how it works so apoligies if its incorrect. I updated this to use a normal function: 

const selectClassGroupnew = async (appId, key) => {
        window.location.replace('/#/serving-point/' + appId + '/' + key);
    }

and then the click works using arrow function as the onClick, but not when using the callback function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have removed the second arrow function and updated callback function as you mentioned and the click event is now working using arrow function as onClick, however still get same error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

Comment: @heady12 can you provide a reproducable example of your code / project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244632/discussion-between-amr-and-heady12).